# Translating "preferences" and "settings"

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico

What is the standard way in Spanish to translate "preferences" (a menu option in computer programs where you can adjust program settings)?

What is the standard way to translate "settings" (an almost-synonym of "preferences," also used for other devices: guitar amplifier settings, cell phone settings, flap settings on airplanes, etc.)?

Comment: There are some other words commonly used in various computing environments for the same kinds of things: "options", "properties", "configuration".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Preferences" could be "[preferencias](http://rae.es/preferencia)", and "settings" could be "[opciones](http://rae.es/opción)" (i.e. "options") or "[ajustes](http://rae.es/ajuste)" (i.e. "adjustments").

Answer (score 3):

You will typically see:

> Preferencias

This translates directly to "preferences". This isn't very technical but you will still see it used very often in software and applications. This relates more to things like colour, size, volume, etc.

Or:

> Configuración

This translates directly to "configuration" and is slightly more technical and typically refers to actual elements that make to a program's behaviour such as "wireless details", video source, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would add to @CesarGon's answer, that an alternative translation of *settings* could be *configuración*, which is literally *configuration* because there's no equivalent for the verb *set* in Spanish.

Comment: Fair enough for *configuración*. However, *set* is often translated as *establecer*.